# Wit.ai - sending pictures via Facebook Messenger Send API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger, messenger, wit.ai

I need my Wit.ai chat bot to respond to certain messages with images, and since I've refactored my code to match the latest messenger example in the node-wit SDK I can't figure out how to do so.

Previously this FB message function worked for me:

```
var newMessage = function (recipientId, msg, atts, cb) {
    var opts = {
        form: {
            recipient: {
                id: recipientId
            },
        }
    }

    if (atts) {
        var message = {
            attachment: {
                "type": "image",
                "payload": {
                    "url": msg
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        var message = {
            text: msg
        }
    }
    opts.form.message = message

    newRequest(opts, function (err, resp, data) {
        if (cb) {
            cb(err || data.error && data.error.message, data)
        }
    })
}
```

Now I've updated to the [node-wit SDK messenger example](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js):

```
const fbMessage = (id, text) => {
     const body = JSON.stringify({
     recipient: { id },
     message: { text },
     });
    const qs = 'access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(FB_PAGE_TOKEN);
    return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?' + qs, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
         body,
    })
    .then(rsp => rsp.json())
    .then(json => {
         if (json.error && json.error.message) {
              throw new Error(json.error.message);
         }
    return json;
    });
};
```

Which I've modified like this to try and make image replies work:

```
const fbMessage = (id, text, atts) => {

    if (atts) {
        var body = {
            attachment: {
                "type": "image",
                "payload": {
                    "url": { text }
                }
            },
        };
    } else {
        var body = JSON.stringify({
            recipient: { id },
            message: { text },
        });
    }
    const qs = 'access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(FB_PAGE_TOKEN);
    return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?' + qs, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body,
    })
    .then(rsp => rsp.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (json.error && json.error.message) {
            throw new Error(json.error.message);
        }
        return json;
    });
};
```

Text messages are being sent as normal, but when I try to send an image attachment, my image url references are just being sent as strings.

[The FB Messenger Send API reference is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
const fbMessage = (id, text) => {

    var x = text.substring(0,4);

    if (x == 'http') {
        var body = JSON.stringify({
            recipient: { id },
            message: {
                attachment: {
                    "type": "image",
                    "payload": {
                        "url": text
                    }
                }
            },
    });

    } else {
        var body = JSON.stringify({
            recipient: { id },
            message: { text },
        });
    }

    const qs = 'access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(FB_PAGE_TOKEN);
    return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?' + qs, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body,
    })
    .then(rsp => rsp.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (json.error && json.error.message) {
            throw new Error(json.error.message);
        }
        return json;
     });
};
```

*NB - This obviously won't work if you plan on sending text replies that are just urls i.e. 'http://example.com'. To get around this you can put any symbol in front of the url address in your message like so: '> http://example.com' and links will work fine.